# How would I calculate the torque of the motor shown in the diagram?

Tags: motors, torque

[image: Diagram]

Torque due to force of gravity:
-Payload: 0.2kg x 0.3m x 9.81 = 0.5886
-Hand: 0.1kg x 0.25m x 9.81 = 0.24525
-Forearm: 0.3kg x 0.1m x 9.81 = 0.2943

Torque due to force of gravity = 1.13Nm

What about torque due to angular acceleration?
I know it is Torque = Moment of inertia x angular acceleration,
However, the motor will be rotating the hand and the forearm around the x-axis.

So, how would I calculate the torque for this motion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to measure the torque needed to turn the arm horizontally to right or left.

If that's the case we calculate the angular moment, I as:

$$ I= \Sigma m_i r^2_i \ = \\ 0.2kg*0.3^2m+0.1kg*0.25^2m+0.3kg*0.1^2m \\=0.18+0.00625+0.003=0.027Nm^2$$

Not that we don't have g factor, and torque is:

$$T=\alpha*I$$

Comment: thank you for your reply!! So do I ignore the torque due to the force of gravity? So I'm talking about this movement: https://makeagif.com/gif/pronation-and-supination-of-the-forearm-pKemMR

Comment: no, if you needto lift you need the torque in X direction, if you need to turn you use the torque in z or y directio. if you dneed both you are dealing with 90 degre right hand moment and gyro precession. and it bocomes substantially more invonlved.

Comment: Ah ok thank you!! So the above calculations from your answer will be all I need. So I will only need the torque due to angular acceleration if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: yes, as long as you measure the arm length from its hing and keep the motions separate you're fine.

Comment: So, T=a*I, where I has been calculated to be 0.027Nm^2 from your calculations. To find a, I will need to specify how fast I want the arm to turn to a specific angle? Is that correct?

Comment: no, how fast your arm accelerates. say you apply a torque of 1Nm then your arm will accelarate roughly 3.3rad/s^2. after 2 seconds it would turn with angular velocity of 6.6 rad/s.

Comment: Sorry, this might be a silly question. But where did you get the 3.3rad/s^2 from?

Comment: 1/0.027Nm. a=T/I.

Comment: 1/0.027 = 37.03 (in degrees) and 0.65 (in radians)?. How do I get the 3.3rad/s^2 from that? Sorry, I know it's probably straight forward.

Comment: no degrees, its 33 or 37radians. my bad, iam driving. all in my head.

Comment: Ah ok, could you double check for me when you have time, if that's ok. Because I am getting 0.65 radians. Drive safe!

Comment: i checked its 37.03rad/s^2.

Comment: So a motor with a torque of more than 0.027Nm would be enough for the arm to turn? But if I want my arm to accelerate faster I would use a motor with more torque.

Comment: hypothetically any motor will do, less power, less acceleration. I would say if your numbers are close, considering friction and incidentals a motor with 1/2Nm torque would do. A lot of confusion arises from mixing acceleration with speed!

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for your help!!:)